# Google Sheets - Multiple users platform - Cant have two or more users at a time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet that will serve as a platform for several users, the sheet allows the user to select several options to generate some statistics and comments. The issue is when I have multiple users connected at the same time, they might want to check different information, selecting different options, so lets say when user 'John' is checking his statistics, the user 'Steve' can go to options and change the inputs, generating a report that 'Steve' wants to check but overwriting 'John's information. :(

So this is a multiuser sheet but only works with 1 person connected at a time.

I can replicate the sheet for each user, so they would have their own sheet, but I can't image updating each copy when necessary.

Do you know any solution in Google Sheets that could address my issue?

Thanks!

Comment: this may be helpful: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19448/multi-user-filter-issue-in-google-spreadsheets

Comment: Hey @Kos thanks for sending this through. This is a nice function, but unfortunately it would not help in my case, I have several resulting tables using query (), from one list of options select, sorry I could not replicate an example to make visualization easier. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: of course, no one says there is perfect solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A long-term solution would be building a [report in Google Data Studio](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6292570).
It's always recommended to have the frontend (User interface) with the backend (data).

After you create a report, you'll only be worried about the data you modify in the Spreadsheet and the users will filter it as they prefer.

You can [connect your spreadsheet](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6370353) with the data and share the data studio link to your users

Comment: Hi @David-Salomon thanks for your suggestion and links, I will definitely try Google Data Studio to to tackle this. Thanks for the input :)